# Firefox not installing properly in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, apt

I'm having a strange issue installing Firefox. Usually I browse Firefox in private mode, but recently I wanted to use the default mode. When I looked for it in the app dock, Firefox wasn't there (Firefox Private Mode is just pinned to the taskbar). I thought that it was a strange issue so I decided to purge Firefox:

```
sudo apt purge firefox
```

Then I reinstalled it:

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

This installed Firefox, but it still wasn't searchable in the app dock. However, it was pinned to the taskbar again. If I launch it, it launches into private again. I was able to install the regular version of Firefox through the Ubuntu Software app, but according to `apt` it's not installed. Anyone know how I can get Firefox from apt to work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you've installed Firefox from snap packages.

You can verify it by typing this command in terminal:

```
sudo snap list
```

If it's on that list, this means is installed as a snap package.

If you want to clear everything up and install firefox from scratch please use these commands in your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge firefox*
sudo snap remove firefox
```

Also you may want to clear any cache and configuration files left.

If there is nothing you want to save (i.e. bookmars, password, etc.), also type this (as user):

```
rm -rf ~/.mozilla ~/.cache/mozilla
```

Also make sure that there is nothing firefox-related left in applications launchers:

```
ls -la ~/.local/share/applications/ | grep firefox
ls -la /usr/share/applications/ | grep firefox
```

Then try to re-install Firefox from apt:

```
apt-get install firefox
```